# AngularJS app hot reload in production

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.5.8 to build the client side of my webapp. I have frequent problems because users don't have the last version of the webapp client side. Is there an easy way to perform hot angular app reloading, in order my users to always have the last version? (I am looking for an alternative of websockets)

Comment: Could just do something like ajax-pings and create a popup/warning on the clientside?

Answer (score 0):

You can poll your server from your client web-app by using setInterval() with an ajax call to some REST endpoint that is capable of returning the most recent version. If that version doesn't match, say, your "version" variable, then you force a reload of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file where you load in all your .js files, you can include a version number in the URL that you increment whenever you do a new build. This will force the user's browser to reload the library from your server as the URL won't exactly match, effectively breaking the cache mechanism and preventing old versions of your code from loading.

The additional data in the URL won't have any effect on the application otherwise.

```
    <script src="js/app.js?v1.2.3"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js?v1.2.3"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js?v1.2.3"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js?v1.2.3"></script>
    <script src="js/components.js?v1.2.3"></script>
```

You would do a search/replace for `v1.2.3` to `v1.2.4` on the next build.

If you're using something like webpack, or some other build pipeline / automation tool, you can do this automatically by including the hash of the library in the file name, and then dynamically updating the URL in the index.html file. When you see files like `app.ad76c09743ef.js`, that's likely how that's being generated. This ensures that even a single character change in your source results in a new, unique hash that will prevent the browser from using an older cached value.

Answer (score 0):

The library I have used for this to good success is https://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster

Each time the user makes a request for a resources, it will force latest version it not on white list.